# -fPIC Flag System-wide?

Tags: compiling, c, compiler

Position Independent Code means that the generated machine code is not dependent on being located at a specific address in order to work. and the jumps are relative.
So is it OK to declare `-fPIC` system wide in a Linux distro. specially the normal intel PC machines?

Comment: This seems a very specific question. I suggest you to take a look on the gentoo documentation. This flag may affect packages but more than that I assume it can break binaries linked against libs which do not support it by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, PIC is a compiler issue and not Linux distro issue. PIC should be allowed to set as a compiler flag instead of hardcoding globally. Not all machine architectures support PIC. If your builds are static (non-shared), you do not need PIC, and it can be inefficient. Some architectures/compilers might have a different equivalent flag, for example, IBM xl compilers have `-qpic` flag. While you ask for intel PC machines, if you happen to create build files for some packages, it might limit their portability.